# Sails js model association

Tags: node.js, orm, sails.js, waterline

I currently have a News model and Comments model. Comments are showed up from X id news so for news with id 5 load comments with id 5.

My models looks like this

```
module.exports = {

    tableName: 'raggaer_aac_news',
    autoCreatedAt: false,
    autoUpdatedAt: false,
    attributes: {
        id: {
            type: 'integer',
            primaryKey: true,
        },
        title: {
            type: 'string',
            defaultsTo: '',
            required: true
        },
        text: {
            type: 'string',
            defaultsTo: '',
            required: true
        },
        getComments: {

            required: false,
            model: 'Comments'
        }
    }
};


module.exports = {

    tableName: 'raggaer_aac_comments',
    attributes: {

        id: {

            required: true,
            type: 'integer',
            primaryKey: true
        },
        created_by: {

            type: 'string',
            required: 'true'
        },
        comment: {

            type: 'string',
            required: 'comment',
            unique: true,
            minLength: 10,
            maxLength: 100
        }
    }
}
```

So on my controller what should I do? as you see I tried on News model adding getComments attribute but that just shows me an error everytime I load a item 'Cannot read property length of undefined'

My controller looks like this

```
News.findById(req.param('id')).exec(function(err, data) {

        if(data.length === 0) {

            return res.redirect('/');
        }

        return res.view('home/news', {info: data[0]});
    });
```

How can I make it so that function will also read comments from comments_table?

Answer (score 1):

For this purposes sails.js has [populate](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/8fc2694a795bc753277f9b970b835dbb384ebfbe/reference/waterline/queries/populate.md) function.

So, you should probably do:

```
News.findById(req.param('id')).populate('getComments').exec(function(err, data) {
    // code ...
});
```

Comment: And how is it matching the comments table? since Im getting getCOmments: undefined

Answer (score 1):

You need to have your news model reference comments as a collection and then do as @glenSwift suggested and use the populate method

news.js

```
module.exports = {

    tableName: 'raggaer_aac_news',
    autoCreatedAt: false,
    autoUpdatedAt: false,
    attributes: {
        id: {
            type: 'integer',
            primaryKey: true,
        },
        title: {
            type: 'string',
            defaultsTo: '',
            required: true
        },
        text: {
            type: 'string',
            defaultsTo: '',
            required: true
        },
        comments: {

            required: false,
            collection: 'comments',
            via: 'news'
        }
    }
};
```

comments.js

```
module.exports = {

    tableName: 'raggaer_aac_comments',
    attributes: {

        id: {

            required: true,
            type: 'integer',
            primaryKey: true
        },
        created_by: {

            type: 'string',
            required: 'true'
        },
        comment: {

            type: 'string',
            required: 'comment',
            unique: true,
            minLength: 10,
            maxLength: 100
        },
        news: {
            model:'news',
            required: true
        }
    }
}
```

in your controller

```
News.findById(req.param('id')).populate('comments').exec(function(err, data) {
    // code ...
});
```

Comment: And hows the association beeing done? Im also getting comments: []

Comment: I might recommend some reading you can populate the associations a few ways. 
http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/ORM/Associations/OnetoMany.html
https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/associations.md